# Basic PHP if statement echo issue

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, opencart

I've got an issue where I want to check, if a product has some options attached to it, I want the output to be different in the list.

So I want the output to be the following:

If the product has options attached to it, it should be formatted like this:

Price From: £1.99

If the product has no options attached to it, it should be formatted like this:

Price: £1.99

The words Price From: And Price: Are localised and being pulled from a separate PHP file.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here, but this is my code:

```
<li>
<?php if(count($options)>1): ?>

<span class="normal"><?php echo $text_price_from; ?></span>

<?php else: ?> 

<span class="normal"><?php echo $text_price; ?></span>

<?php endif; ?>

<span class="price"><?php echo $price; ?></span>
</li>
```

In my HTML output, it just shows the span as empty.

Strange this is, it WORKS if I just write the work statically in the first span. So for example, this works:

```
<li>
<?php if(count($options)>1): ?>

<span class="normal">From:</span>

<?php else: ?> 

<span class="normal"><?php echo $text_price; ?></span>

<?php endif; ?>

<span class="price"><?php echo $price; ?></span>
</li>
```

Anyone got any ideas? The platform is OpenCart.

Thanks Mel

Comment: lookls like the variable you try to echo is empty..

Comment: @jonhopkins it's an alternative syntax for PHP. More readable when you want to inject PHP into HTML. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @Sven Thanks. I just found that myself haha

Comment: Use alert and see what your variable is holding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language file will need to have a

```
$_['text_price_from'] = 'From:';
```

and your controller needs to have

```
$this->data['text_price_from'] = $this->language->get('text_price_from');
```

This is most likely the issue - you are missing one of those pieces of the puzzle. If it's not, then the only other explanation is the variable is being unset in either the language file, controller or possibly the template

Comment: Awesome thanks... yes... I was missing the info in the controller.

Comment: Hi Jay, 

If I wanted to do the same function on the category page, i.e.... display some text if options were greater than 1, how can I go about doing so?

It seems that the $options count is not working, I tried adding this but it doesent work either... 

<?php if(count($product['options']>1)): ?>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks Mel

Comment: That's more complex, you'll need to individually load options for the products in the controller, assign those to the product array and then test for the option count on the template again

Answer (score 0):

Try to var_dump those variables and see what you get.

```
var_dump(count($options) > 1, $text_price_from, $text_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether `$text_price_from` has a value or is set. Eventhough condition is suitable if the variable is empty it will display nothing.